# Cannot have two Streamlit forms in the same page

Tags: forms, streamlit

I'm looking to add both a "login" and "sign up" feature to a page in Streamlit.

From what I read in the docs, the following should work since I have two separate forms with unique keys.

But the result is the data in the each form doesn't show up. The `submit` result of the form submit isn't triggered.

```py
    show_create_account: bool = st.button("Create account", use_container_width=True)

    if show_create_account:
        with st.form(key="new_user_and_login"):
            new_email = st.text_input(label="Email")
            new_password = st.text_input(label="Password", type="password")
            new_password_confirm = st.text_input(
                label="Confirm password", type="password"
            )

            new_submit = st.form_submit_button(label="Create account")
            if new_submit:
                if new_password != new_password_confirm:
                    st.error("Passwords do not match.")
                else:
                    x = get_auth().create_user_with_email_and_password(
                        new_email, new_password
                    )
                    print("ACCOUNT CREATED: ", x)

    else:
        with st.form(key="login_user"):
            email = st.text_input(label="Email")
            password = st.text_input(label="Password", type="password")

            submit = st.form_submit_button("Log in")
            if submit:
                if email and password:
                    auth_user(email, password)
                    st.success("Login success!")

                else:
                    st.error("Email and password needed.")
```

What I've tried:

- Using only the "login" and only the "signup" form: Works as intended
- Have both features on the page without a `show_create_account` button: Works as intended, but I'd like to have only one on the page
- Using st.forms without the with notation: Same result

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with two columns:

```
import streamlit as st
col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

with col1:
   # Logic for form 1

with col2:
   # Logic for form 2
```

Then fill each column with a form.